# NHibernate Guid.Comb does Insert followed by Update

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have the following entity:

```
public class Entity
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual String Name { get; set; }
}
```

With the following Mapping:

```
public class EntityMap : ClassMap<Entity>
{
    public EntityMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
        Map(x => x.Name).Not.Nullable();
    }
}
```

I get an error executing the following code:

```
using(var tx = Session.BeginTransaction())
{        
    var entity = GetSomethingFromTheDatabase();
    if(entity == null)
    {
        Session.Save(new Entity());
    }
    entity.Name = "test";
    tx.Commit();
}
```

The error is:

```
NHibernate.PropertyValueException : not-null property references a null or transient value Entity.Name
```

When I make the property `Name` nullable, everything works fine, but NHibernate issues an Insert-statement (with `Name=null`) followed by an Update-statement (with `Name='test'`)

So: **Why does NHibernate try to insert my entity before updating it with the values?** That's how the autoincrement id-generator works. We try to avoid this with Guid.Comb. If I read the documentation, `Guid.Comb` should generate the ID without going to the database.

EDIT:

- I clarified the code a bit to show what we want to do. We want to insert an Entity when it is not present in the database.
- The database statements are only executed when the transaction is committed. So when `Save()` is called, nothing happens. But when `tx.Commit()` is called, the insert is  issued and immediately followed by the update. I would think that NHibernate would save all changed values and put them in one Insert.

Answer (score 1):

Is it issuing the inserts as soon as .Save is executed?

Maybe you should set the `entity.Name` before you issue the Save.

I've always had the strong opinion that if you are creating your entity the constructor should take all of the required fields to construct the object.  A field in the database that is not nullable is a required field.

Comment: I would take the `Name` property in the constructor and throw argument null exceptions if name is null when passed to the constructor.  You could then leave your existing update to the property below the save.

Comment: Yes, but still: Why both an update and an Insert? (We fixed it by putting the `Save` at the bottom)

Comment: Because I think when you issue the save it adds that action to the "unit of work" (ISession).  After you update one of the properties that is a separate action which is also recorded in the unit of work.

Answer (score 0):

Because you Save it before you modify it? When you call `.Save` the entity gets validated and if needed persisted or else waits before it either gets flushed or the transaction is completed. When you call Save it has a property with a null value and so you get the exception.

```
Console.WriteLine(session.Save(..))
```

Returns the generated ID for your entity. You could see if that value corresponds with the value in the database.

But I would indeed assume that no roundtrip would be made to the database yet until either flushed or committed.